# attempt to index local 'params' (a nil value) error

Tags: indexing, parameters, lua, parameter-passing, game-development

This is the full Error

src/states/game/PlayState.lua:21: attempt to index local 'params' (a nil value)

This is the Code where the error occurs, on the line where we call levelmaker.generate specificaly because of params.levelwidth.

```
    function PlayState:enter(params)
    self.level = LevelMaker.generate(params.levelwidth or 100, 10, self.levelcount)
    self.tileMap = self.level.tileMap
    self.levelcount = 1 or params.level

    self.player = Player({
        x = 0, y = 0,
        width = 16, height = 20,
        texture = 'green-alien',
        stateMachine = StateMachine {
            ['idle'] = function() return PlayerIdleState(self.player) end,
            ['walking'] = function() return PlayerWalkingState(self.player) end,
            ['jump'] = function() return PlayerJumpState(self.player, self.gravityAmount) end,
            ['falling'] = function() return PlayerFallingState(self.player, self.gravityAmount) end
        },
        map = self.tileMap,
        level = self.level,
        score = params.score or 0
    })

    self:spawnEnemies()

    self.player:changeState('falling')
end
```

The function is from called here and I also pass the params from here:

```
function generatePole(width, flagPoleColor, Ypos, Xpos, part)
  return GameObject {
    texture = 'flags',
    x = (Xpos - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
    y = (Ypos - 1) * TILE_SIZE - 4,
    width = 6,
    height = 16,
    frame = flagPoleColor + part * FLAG_OFFSET,
    collidable = true,
    consumable = true,
    solid = false,

    onConsume = function(player, object)
        gSounds['pickup']:play()
        player.score = player.score + 250

        gStateMachine:change('play', {
            score = player.score,
            levelwidth = levelwidth + 10,
            level = levelcounter + 1
        })
    end
 }
end
```

This is my state machine in which the function gstatemachine:change is written.

```
StateMachine = Class{}

function StateMachine:init(states)
    self.empty = {
        render = function() end,
        update = function() end,
        enter = function() end,
        exit = function() end
    }
    self.states = states or {} -- [name] -> [function that returns states]
    self.current = self.empty
end

function StateMachine:change(stateName, enterParams)
    assert(self.states[stateName]) -- state must exist!
    self.current:exit()
    self.current = self.states[stateName]()
    self.current:enter(enterParams)
end

function StateMachine:update(dt)
    self.current:update(dt)
end

function StateMachine:render()
    self.current:render()
end
```

Comment: well in line 21 of PlayState.lua you index a nil value. find out why it is nil. what stops you from finding out why it is nil? where do you think it is defined? from the provided code it is not clear how those functions are called. Which of those lines is line 21?  params is indexed in PlayState.enter which might be called in StateMachine.change which is only in the function definition of GameObject.onConsume.